# GTK+ notebook - unable to print current label text

Tags: c, gtk

**Hello everyone,**

I'm currently trying to convert my PyGTK application to C, everything was 
working as expected until I hit an issue with retrieving label name of my notebook widget.

Below is a short example of what I'm trying to achieve..

```
GtkBuilder      *builder = NULL;
GtkWidget       *window = NULL;
GtkWidget       *notebook = NULL;
GError     *error = NULL;

void on_page_switch(GtkNotebook *notebook, gpointer data)
{
    // gtk_notebook_get_tab_label_text(GtkNotebook *notebook,GtkWidget *child)
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new ();

    if( ! gtk_builder_add_from_file( builder, "data/glade.glade", &error ) )
    {
        g_warning( "%s", error->message );
        g_free( error );
        return( 1 );
    }

    window = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window1"));
    gtk_window_set_resizable (GTK_WINDOW(window), FALSE);
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC (on_window_destroy), NULL);

    notebook = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "notebook1"));
    g_signal_connect(GTK_NOTEBOOK (notebook), "switch-page", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(on_page_switch), NULL);

    gtk_builder_connect_signals (builder, NULL);
    g_object_unref (G_OBJECT (builder));

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

Could you please give me some pointers as how to get the current tab's label name?

I believe it should be this function  `gtk_notebook_get_tab_label_text(GtkNotebook *notebook, GtkWidget *child)` , however I was unable to get it working too.

Apologies for my bad english.

Thanks in advance,
Alex

**/// EDIT ////**

It was actualy the call-back function it self that was wrong.. 
I have missed couple of pointers that are passed with the "switch-page" event.

```
void on_page_switch(GtkNotebook * notebook, GtkWidget *page, guint page_num, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkWidget * child = gtk_notebook_get_nth_page(notebook, page_num);
    printf(" -> %i \n", gtk_notebook_page_num(notebook, child));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct, you should be able to use [`gtk_notebook_get_tab_label_text()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkNotebook.html#gtk-notebook-get-tab-label-text) to do this.

You need a pointer to the child widget (page content) whose label you're interested in, you can use [`gtk_notebook_get_nth_page()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkNotebook.html#gtk-notebook-get-nth-page) to get that if you don't have the notebook children handy.

It's hard to help more since you didn't specify what problems you ran in to when you tried it.

Comment: ok but in this case I can retrieve only the label I have defined in gtk_notebook_get_nth_page(). The fact is that , I would like to get a children of current tab label. Is there any way of getting this information?

In Python I only had to do this.. 

    `def on_page_switch(self, nb, page, page_num):
        child = nb.get_nth_page(page_num)
        print nb.get_tab_label_text(child)`

Comment: @Wracker Your tabs contain more widgets than just single `GtkLabel`s?

Comment: I've got 3 tabs , and each of them has it's own label with text in it.

Comment: @Wracker Okay ... You should be able to use the exact same calls, as I said above? Just print the string with `print("%s\n", gtk_notebook_get_tab_label_text(/* blah */));` and be done.

Comment: ok it's working, but I have to exactly say which page to use. 
    `GtkWidget * tmp = gtk_notebook_get_nth_page(notebook, 1);`
    `printf(" -> %s \n", gtk_notebook_get_tab_label_text(notebook, GTK_WIDGET(tmp)));` 

is there a function to return the current page number?

Comment: Good. And yes of course there is, didn't you follow the links and look at the API docs? How did you write your Python program to begin with? :) See [`gtk_notebook_get_current_page()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkNotebook.html#gtk-notebook-get-current-page).

Comment: I guess that would be the  `gtk_notebook_get_current_page()` .. although it's giving me strange results. It prints the page number , but it somehow mixes up the numbers. it returns a label_text from different tab. I'm going to investigate what number does it print.

Comment: it's somehow not returning the correct page number. Any ideas why it's so?

Comment: Please isolate the code, and *post a new question*. When doing so, *please* include more detail than "not returning the correct page number".

Comment: Thanks for your help @unwind , I  seem to have figured it out. See my first post. I was missing couple of pointer in the call-back function.